# How to ouput vertically to excel?

Tags: python, csv, web, web-scraping

Here is my code, basically I wanted to output the variable "final" to excel and I wanted it to be printed in one column. My current writing code will only write the results to one row in excel..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import csv

r = requests.get("https://www.autocodes.com/obd-code-list/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"scroller"})

for item in g_data:
    regex = '.html">(.+?)</a>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("https://www.autocodes.com/obd-code-list/")
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    final = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)


with open('index4.csv','w') as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  writer.writerow(['company'])#row?
  writer.writerows([final])
```

Any possible fix for this? Thanks, I am just new to Python and just studying it with little programming knowledge.

Comment: csv files are row based.  To write to a 'column' you would need to write one character per row.

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks buddy, without your info I'm stuck with the wrong perception..anyway I added a for loop in the writing section..and it fixed it..